# PyQt5 код не открывает сайты

Tags: python, pyqt5, браузер

Вот код:

```py
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon

class SimpleBrowser(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.browser = QWebEngineView()
        self.browser.setUrl(QUrl("https://youtube.com/"))

        self.setCentralWidget(self.browser)

        navbar = QToolBar()
        self.addToolBar(navbar)

        back_btn = QAction('Назад', self)
        back_btn.setStatusTip('Назад к предыдущей странице')
        back_btn.triggered.connect(self.browser.back)
        navbar.addAction(back_btn)

        forward_btn = QAction('Вперед', self)
        forward_btn.setStatusTip('Вперед к следующей странице')
        forward_btn.triggered.connect(self.browser.forward)
        navbar.addAction(forward_btn)

        reload_btn = QAction('Обновить', self)
        reload_btn.setStatusTip('Обновить страницу')
        reload_btn.triggered.connect(self.browser.reload)
        navbar.addAction(reload_btn)

        exit_btn = QAction('Выход', self)
        exit_btn.setStatusTip('Выйти из программы')
        exit_btn.triggered.connect(self.close)
        navbar.addAction(exit_btn)

        self.setWindowTitle('Простенький браузер')
        self.setWindowIcon(QIcon('icon.png'))

    def resizeEvent(self, event):
        self.browser.setFixedSize(self.centralWidget().size())

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
QApplication.setApplicationName("Простенький браузер")
window = SimpleBrowser()
window.show()
app.exec_()
```

Браузер открывается, но не грузит сайт.
Изначальный план был: написать браузер, который открывает только один сайт - и все.
С этой библиотекой работаю первый раз и, прочитав форумы, написал такое.

Comment: У меня всё работает. У вас в консоли выводятся какие-то ошибки?

Comment: @AvidCoder нет ошибок нету, просто белый экран не грузит сайт который указан(youtube.com)

Comment: @AvidCoder может нужно указать место для куки файлов ?

Comment: Mister Ban, попробуйте объяснить лучше, что вы хотите сделать и что у вас не получается. Какой сайт не грузится у вас и покажите строку, которой вы его пытаетесь загрузить. Приложение следует запускать в консоли/терминале/CMD.

Comment: приложение запускается и заходит в сайт который указан, в данном случай youtube, это как приложение с WEB интерфейсом запускает сайт как приложение.

Comment: @S.Nick я использую VS code обязательно в консоли запускать? раньше я все проекты запускал либо на f5 либо на кнопку Run Python File

Comment: @S.Nick код работает, но просто вместо сайта белый экран

Comment: Mister Ban, sorry. 1. я не понял ваших объяснений о том , что вы хотите сделать и что у вас не получается. 2. Да, приучите себя всегда запускать приложения в консоли/терминале/CMD. 3. О каком сайте вы говорите, вместо которого белый экран

Comment: write to you in English? @S.Nick

Comment: @S.Nick это обычный google браузер, но заходит он только в один сайт по URL в коде и все

Comment: Mister Ban, sorry. вам же написали в первом комментарии, что код, который вы предоставили, работает так, как в нем написано. У меня ваш пример работает и я не понимаю что вы хотите сделать, и чем вам помочь.

Comment: @S.Nick оно открывает сайт youtube.com? мне нужно чтобы он открывал сайты, у меня не открывает

Comment: Mister Ban, да, в приведенном примере, строкой `self.browser.setUrl(QUrl("https://youtube.com/"))` открывает сайт `youtube.com`